# Empantanado con un boton submit que no funciona después de usar tinyMCE

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce

Estoy con un formulario donde cargo una noticia. Tengo un titulo, un resumen, el cuerpo de la nota. Eso lo manejo dentro de un form asi:

```
<form class="ui form" role="form" action="guardar.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    <label>Título:</label>
    <input id="titulo" type="text" name="titulo" required>

    <label>Resumen / Bajada:</label>
    <textarea id="resumen" name="resumen" required></textarea>

    <label>Texto:</label>
    <textarea id="texto" name="texto" required></textarea>

    <button class="ui green button" type="submit">Publicar</button>
    <a href="noticias.php" class="ui blue button">Noticias</a>
</form>
```

Mas abajo tengo otro form con el que manejo la carga de una foto para la noticia.

```
<form class="ui form" role="form" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    (...)
</form>
```

(en los "..." va un script de un plugin que coloca un botón para subir la imagen) 
Antes de implementar tinyMCE funcionaba todo perfecto. Desde que puse esa funcionalidad no funcionó más. Lo extraño es que no arroja ningún error.
En guardar.php tengo esto manejando

```
session_start();
require '../../includes/conexion.php';
include '../../includes/funcs.php';

$error = "";
$fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];

//Manejo de las textareas
$allowedTags='<p><strong><em><u><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6><img><li><ol><ul><span><div><br><ins><del><small>';
if($_POST['resumen']!='') {
    $sResumen = strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['resumen']),$allowedTags);
    echo $sResumen;
} else {
    $sResumen = "";
}

if($_POST['texto']!='') {
    $sTexto = strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['texto']),$allowedTags);
    echo $sTexto;
} else {
    $sTexto = "";
}

//$resumen = nl2br($_POST['resumen']);
//$texto = nl2br($_POST['texto']);

if (isset($_POST['vigente'])) {
    $vigente = 1;
} else{
    $vigente = 0;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO noticias (fecha, titulo, resumen, texto, vigente) VALUES ('$fecha', '$titulo', '$sResumen', '$sTexto', '$vigente')";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
$id_insert = $mysqli->insert_id;

$nombre_fichero = "../../images/noticias/".$id_insert.".jpg";
$sql = $mysqli->query("UPDATE noticias SET(imagen='"$nombre_fichero"') WHERE id='$id_insert'");
if($sql){
    //Todo ok
}else{
    print 'Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error;
}
```

Ahi como pueden ver tengo comentado las dos lineas que antes funcionaban perfecto con los textareas:

```
$resumen = nl2br($_POST['resumen']);
$texto = nl2br($_POST['texto']);
```

Comment: ¿Y quitando los comentarios manda algún error?¿Las variables `$resumen` y `$texto` se guardan correctamente?¿tinyMCE lo usas nada más para el botón de subida? Porque eso PHP ya lo tiene integrado sin usar librerías de terceros.

Comment: acabo de eliminar todo rastro de tinymce y anda perfecto... es el maldito tinymce el que me esta haciendo alguna mala jugada... levantan bien los datos... el problema es que yo no tengo drama en escribir en el textarea con codigo html pero el usuario comun que quiera poner bullets... se le complica... que se yo...

Comment: $nombre_fichero = "../../images/noticias/".$id_insert.".jpg";
$sql = $mysqli->query("UPDATE noticias SET(imagen='"$nombre_fichero"') WHERE id='$id_insert'");
if($sql){
    //Todo ok
}else{
    print 'Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error;
} esto me da error... no me deja hacer este update...

Comment: Prueba a ver si quitando los `required` de los textarea funciona.